# Analyzing LimeSurvey ranking data in R

Tags: r, limesurvey

I've used LimeSurvey to capture ranking information for 8 options across a large class of students. I've exported the results as CSV, and I get something like the following...

```
Team1 Option7 Option4 Option6 Option1 Option2 Option3 Option5 Option8
Team2 Option4 Option3 Option1 Option2 Option7 Option8 Option6 Option5
...
```

... where the ranking goes from lowest to highest (e.g. Team1 most preferred Option7). What I'm trying to turn this into is something like...

```
Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4 Option5 Option6 Option7 Option8
4       5       6       2       7       3       1       8
3       4       2       1       8       7       5       6
...
```

... in as "R like" a way as possible (e.g. avoiding nested `for` loops and the like). My end goal is to generate histograms for each option showing how often they were voted first, second, etc. I have a suspicion that `reshape` and it's ilk might help, but having to use the "position" information is tripping me up.

Any assistance gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
 dat <- read.table(text="Team1 Option7 Option4 Option6 Option1 Option2 Option3 Option5 Option8
     Team2 Option4 Option3 Option1 Option2 Option7 Option8 Option6 Option5")

 cbind( dat[,1,drop=FALSE ], t( apply(dat[ , -1], 1, order) ) )
#     V1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#1 Team1 4 5 6 2 7 3 1 8
#2 Team2 3 4 2 1 8 7 5 6
```

The drop =FALSE is needed to prevent the column from becoming a vector. The transpose is needed because apply returns a matrix in column major order.

Comment: Looks perfect; thanks! From your answer I've learned about `order`, the `-1` index, the `drop` parameter, `cbind`, and the basic `apply` (as opposed to the more commonly seen `sapply`)... an awesome information density!